# htaccess overriding rewrite rule if parameter exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having an issue with my htaccess where parameters in the URL are being overridden by an existing rule, but I don't know how to modify it.

When I visit the URL `/trade/?sold=1`, it rewrites that to just `/trade/`, which is not desired because the parameter `sold=1` isn't passed to PHP and therefore the page remains unchanged.

Here is my full rewrite section in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 # You may need to un-comment the following lines
 # Options +FollowSymlinks
 # To make sure that rewritten dir or file (/|.html) will not load dir.php in case it exist
 # Options -MultiViews
 # REMEBER YOU ONLY NEED TO STARD MOD REWRITE ONCE
 RewriteEngine On

 # Uncomment the statement below if you want to make use of
 # HTTP authentication and it does not already work.
 # This could be required if you are for example using PHP via Apache CGI.
 # RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

 # REWRITE BASE
 RewriteBase /

 # Zulu fix crumbs ?f= etc. for each forum (currently disabled with pound sign)

 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=1($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /database? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=2($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /uniques? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=3($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /runewords? [L,R=301]
 ##RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=4($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /sets? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=5($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /base? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=6($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /recipes? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=7($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /monsters? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=8($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /npcs? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=9($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /skills? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=10($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /zones? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=11($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /quests? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=12($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /misc? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=13($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /tools? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=14($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /builds? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=15($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /articles? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=16($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /trade? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=17($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /forums? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=18($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /feedback? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=21($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /bug-reports? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=23($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /contributions? [L,R=301]
 #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)f=24($|&)
 #RewriteRule ^viewforum\.php$ /price-check? [L,R=301]

 # HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO FORCE CANONICAL DOMAIN
 # Define fully qualified ssl aware protocol
 # RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
 # RewriteRule ^.*$ - [env=HttpFullProto:http%2://]
 # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^diablo2$ [NC]
 # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:HttpFullProto}diablo2/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]

 # DO NOT GO FURTHER IF THE REQUESTED FILE / DIR DOES EXISTS
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule . - [L]
 # FORUM INDEX REWRITERULE WOULD STAND HERE IF USED. "forum" REQUIRES TO BE SET AS FORUM INDEX
 # RewriteRule ^forum\.html$ /index.php [QSA,L,NC]
 # FORUM ALL MODES
 RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ /viewforum.php?f=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
 # TOPIC WITH VIRTUAL FOLDER ALL MODES
 RewriteRule ^(forum|[a-z0-9_-]*-f)([0-9]+)/(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?f=$2&t=$4&start=$6 [QSA,L,NC]
 # TOPIC WITHOUT FORUM ID & DELIM ALL MODES
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]*)/?(topic|[a-z0-9_-]*-t)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /viewtopic.php?forum_uri=$1&t=$3&start=$5 [QSA,L,NC]
 # PROFILES THROUGH USERNAME
 RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/?$ /memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&un=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
 # USER MESSAGES THROUGH USERNAME
 RewriteRule ^member/([^/]+)/(topics|posts)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ /search.php?author=$1&sr=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
 # GROUPS ALL MODES
 RewriteRule ^(group|[a-z0-9_-]*-g)([0-9]+)(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /memberlist.php?mode=group&g=$2&start=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
 # POSTS
 RewriteRule ^post([0-9]+)\.html$ /viewtopic.php?p=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
 # ACTIVE TOPICS
 RewriteRule ^active-topics(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=active_topics&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
 # UNANSWERED TOPICS
 RewriteRule ^unanswered(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unanswered&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
 # NEW POSTS
 RewriteRule ^newposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=newposts&start=$2&sr=topics [QSA,L,NC]
 # UNREAD POSTS
 RewriteRule ^unreadposts(-([0-9]+))?\.html$ /search.php?search_id=unreadposts&start=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
 # THE TEAM
 RewriteRule ^the-team\.html$ /memberlist.php?mode=team [QSA,L,NC]
 # HERE IS A GOOD PLACE TO ADD OTHER PHPBB RELATED REWRITERULES
 
 # FORUM WITHOUT ID & DELIM ALL MODES
 # THESE LINES MUST BE LOCATED AT THE END OF YOUR HTACCESS TO WORK PROPERLY
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)/?(page([0-9]+)\.html)?$ /viewforum.php?forum_uri=$1&start=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
 # FIX RELATIVE PATHS : FILES
 RewriteRule ^(style\.php|ucp\.php|mcp\.php|faq\.php|posting\.php|download/file\.php|report\.php|adm/index\.php|cron\.php)$ /$1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
 # FIX RELATIVE PATHS : IMAGES
 RewriteRule ^.+/(styles/.*|images/.*|assets/.*|ext/.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,NC,R=301]
 #
 # The following 3 lines will rewrite URLs passed through the front controller
 # to not require app.php in the actual URL. In other words, a controller is
 # by default accessed at /app.php/my/controller, but can also be accessed at
 # /my/controller
 #
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Could somebody help me identify the culprit rule and modify it so that any URL parameters are always passed and not 'deleted'?

Comment: Hey anubhava - I did and the redirect is a 301 from /trade/?sold=1 to /trade/ as explained in my question. This is the redirect I don't want, I want it to always strictly continue to the page with the parameters intact, I don't want them removed.

Comment: I have tested with all of your code and this redirection didn't happen so that might be inside your code

Comment: I've provided my htaccess code in the question - which was how can I disable the parameters from being rewritten - the parameters are clearly being rewritten, as per the htaccess, and hence the 301 redirect. So the issue is in the htaccess file, not elsewhere in my code?

Comment: I concur with anubhava, there does not appear to be anything in the `.htaccess` file you've posted that would trigger such a redirect. (?) "which was how can I disable the parameters from being rewritten" - what do you mean by that? is it only happening for `/trade/?sold=1`, or is it happening for any URL with URL parameters?

Comment: It doesn't happen when I use standard parameters such as /trade/?st=1 (sort by 1 day), but does happen when I use this custom parameter. I want to visit /trade/?sold=1 and not be redirected to /trade/. Edit: suppose this is deeper than .htaccess then.

Comment: I followed your instructions and tested with cacheing disabled, so no, it's not that.

Comment: "It doesn't happen when I use standard parameters such as /trade/?st=1" - there's certainly nothing in your `.htaccess` file that differentiates between URL parameters (all the rules that do are commented out) - so this further suggests there is _something else_ that is triggering the redirect.